# want to count time in activity when it starts

Tags: java, android

a small time based question > I want to get timer in activity I already tryed this code but it runs so fast I offen get " 0 "  I want to program to run with no sleep . but to count from  0 to 60 sec

```
      package com.okok;


 import java.util.ArrayList;
 import java.util.List;

 import android.content.Context;
 import android.graphics.Bitmap;
 import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
 import android.graphics.Canvas;
 import android.graphics.Color;
 import android.os.Handler;
 import android.os.SystemClock;
 import android.view.MotionEvent;
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
 import android.view.SurfaceView;
 import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
 import android.widget.Chronometer;



  class GameView extends SurfaceView {
   //private Bitmap bmp;
   // Chronometer mChronometer;
   private SurfaceHolder holder;
   private GameLoopThread gameLoopThread;
   private List<Sprite> sprites = new ArrayList<Sprite>();
   private long lastClick;
private Bitmap bmpBlood;
 Handler m_handler;
 Runnable m_handlerTask ;


private List<TempSprite> temps = new ArrayList<TempSprite>();

   public GameView(Context context) {
         super(context);
         gameLoopThread = new GameLoopThread(this);
         holder = getHolder();
         holder.addCallback(new Callback() {
                @Override
                public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                }
                @Override
                public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
                       createSprites();
                       gameLoopThread.setRunning(true);
                       gameLoopThread.start();
                }
                @Override
                public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format,
                              int width, int height) {
                }
         });
         bmpBlood = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.blast2);
   }


   private void createSprites() {
         sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.greenenact));
        // sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.greenenact));
      //   sprites.add(createSprite(R.drawable.greenenact));

   }
   private Sprite createSprite(int resouce) {
         Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), resouce);
         return new Sprite(this, bmp);
   }
   @Override
   protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
         canvas.drawColor(Color.rgb(21, 181, 195));
         for (int i = temps.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
             temps.get(i).onDraw(canvas);
       }


         final int count=0;
              m_handler = new Handler();
               m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
               {
                   @Override 
                   public void run() { 
                      // do something

                        if(count=60)
                        {
                            m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
                        } 
                        count++;
                        m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 5000);

         for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
             sprite.onDraw(canvas);             

              }

                   }
              };
              m_handlerTask.run(); 
   }







@Override
   public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
         if (System.currentTimeMillis() - lastClick > 500) {
                lastClick = System.currentTimeMillis();
             synchronized (getHolder()) {
             float x = event.getX();
                float y =event.getY();

                   for (int i = sprites.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                        Sprite sprite = sprites.get(i);
                        if (sprite.isCollition(x, y)) {
                              sprites.remove(sprite);


                            temps.add(new TempSprite(temps, this, x, y, bmpBlood));
                              break;
                        }
                    }
                }
         }
         return true;
   }

   }
```

this is my program I  have only one error 
 can not change count from int to a boolean error

I don't want to use sleep method because my application have sleep method that affect  my animation

or give me a program that counts 0 to 60  sec and displays which runs without a sleep method

Comment: You can use a handler. You want a timer?

Comment: yes  LIKE .when timer reach 5 i want to sent 3 enemy units to attack .. when the timer reach 10 i want to sent 3 more enemy units to attack .. when the timer reach 15 i want to send 3 more ... like that so oN till 60 secs – Anu just now edit

Comment: why is that you have a main method like java. are you coding for android?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to call the method to start and how to get the value of int a](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19367796/how-to-call-the-method-to-start-and-how-to-get-the-value-of-int-a)

Answer (score 0):

> Use chronometer instead. [Here is example](http://ezhilsigamani.blogspot.in/2011/02/chronometer-example-android.html) ,
>   [Example 2](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/stop-watch-example/)

Comment: i want it to be simple like that :) seeing the examples u gave its nice  .. i  just want to have timer in coding not in visual !!

Comment: LIKE .when timer reach 5 i want to sent 3 enemy units to attack .. when the timer reach 10 i want to sent 3 more enemy units to attack .. when the timer reach 15 i want to send 3 more ... like that so oN till 60 secs

Comment: yes u can with this chronometer just try sample code once, then u can work easly

Comment: i used this code : from the example'long et = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mChronometer.getBase();     
             
          if(et>0){
           for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
                           
                  }  }
          if(et>20){
           for (Sprite sprite : sprites) {
                  
              }  }  but i got error

Comment: these are the errors i got :( sorry for asking so many questions .. i am new to android but i really really want to learn

Comment: @Anu this does not help solve the problem.1. edit your question and post the relevant updated code. 2. post the relevant logcat.

Comment: sorry i am all exited and in anxious . i will check the codes once again and ask a question    Thanks to @Monica

Answer (score 0):

Use a Handler

```
 Handler m_handler;
 Runnable m_handlerTask ;
 int count=0;
      m_handler = new Handler();
       m_handlerTask = new Runnable()
       {
           @Override 
           public void run() { 
              // do something

                if(count=60)
                {
                    m_handler.removeCallbacks(m_handlerTask);
                } 
                count++:  
                m_handler.postDelayed(m_handlerTask, 1000);
                  // repeat some task every 1 second    

           }
      };
      m_handlerTask.run();
```

Comment: i tryed this but i get error saying change m_handeler to final  and asking count is a long cant convert to boolean ..

Comment: You need to declare the variables as class member or make it final.

Comment: i don't see any run method in what you have posted. you need to post some more relevant info if you want your problem solved and you have a main method in android!